# How to validate a content of a field without pressing a button?

Tags: javascript

I need to validate the integrity of my email and I am doing it by pressing a "validate" button.
I wonder if there is a way to do the same without pressing a button? Say, just exiting the email field, clicking another field for example (`field2`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get Text Input Field Value in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>


    <p >Enter an email address:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your email here..." id="myInput">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field 2" id="field2">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Validate</button>
    
    <script>
        function getInputValue(){
            // Selecting the input element and get its value 
            var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

            const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            // return re.test(inputVal);
            resultat = re.test(inputVal);
            // document.write(resultat);

            if (resultat) {
                alert(inputVal+" is valid");
                } else {
                alert(inputVal+" is NOT valid");
                }
                return false;
            }
 
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `keyPress`, `onBlur`, and several other events the user is doing anyway when filling out a form are available to you.  Hook into one of those to do your validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellma's answer is correct, HTML has this functionality and you'd be hard pressed to come up with an implementation better than the browsers. That said, if you need additional validation on top of what the browser provides you could use the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event). Instead of the `onclick` attribute on your `button`, you could add an `onblur` attribute to your input to run the `getInputValue` function whenever the user's focus leaves that input element. This would look like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your email here..." id="myInput" onBlur="getInputValue()">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built in functionality of html via

```
<input type="email" required>
```

If you then applied css through the pseudo-class :invalid, you would see a visual hint.

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

Check these ressources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Answer (score 2):

Look at onBlur event

```js
const onBlur = () => {
  const test = document.getElementById("test");
  // here you have your value 
  test.value = test.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" onblur="onBlur()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyUp event, try this:

```js
function validate(e){
  inputText = e.target.value;
  console.log(inputText);
  if(inputText == 'condition'){
    console.log('condition passed!')
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="validate(event)">
```